# How to write a LINQ query if index usage is necessary?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method to get information about if a URL source supports Accept-Ranges.

The method is:

```
bool getAcceptRangeHeaderValue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < resp.Headers.AllKeys.Count; i++)
    {
        if (resp.Headers.AllKeys[i].Contains("Range"))
            return resp.Headers[i].Contains("byte");
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to write the method in LINQ to be shorter. But I couldn't do it because of the index usage. How to write it in LINQ?

Comment: Try: 
return (from s in resp.Headers.AllKeys where s.Contains("Range") select s).Any(n=> n.Contains("byte"));

Comment: IMHO it should be efficient than the linq solution, as it does not require to convert to `IEnumerable` and filter by `Any`

Comment: @AmmarSalman, in your query `s` is from `AllKeys` but we need to get it from `Headers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really *shorter*, but if you really want to use LINQ, you can write:

```
return a.Headers.AllKeys
    .Select((v, ind) =>
    new {
        HeaderName = v,
        HeaderValue = a.Headers[ind],
    })
    .Any(g => g.HeaderName.Contains("Range") && g.HeaderValue.Contains("byte"))
```

Comment: Although it isn't shorter, I learned something new. Thanks Mr. Rob.

Comment: @AliTor No worries mate

Comment: But I have a question. In `(v,ind)` pair, how we know `v` is the `HeaderName` and `ind` is the index. Does the parameters pass always like it?

Comment: @AliTor Yes, this will always be the case - it's an overload of `.Select(a => a)`